# What is the best way of standardization/normalization of multiple variables for comparing slope and intercept of a linear model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, linear-regression

I'm analyzing a dataset of game players. The dataset includes 13 game modes. I want to compare the learning progress of the players in a particular skill across game modes. For instance, 'score' of players in different game modes.

To achieve this goal, I fitted a linear model to 'scores' of a player. Then, I take the mean value of intercept and slope of the fitted line for all players in a game mode. To compare different game modes, I should do standardization. So I face these questions:

1. Should I do standardization on the data of all game modes or for each game mode separately?
2. What is the best way of standardization for this task?

I scaled the data for each game mode to 0-1, but the intercept is negative sometimes.

Comment: You'll get more interest in this question at stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you.